# で in the usage of サッカーで怪我をした etc

Tags: particles

What is this で particle here?
It's not a time or a place
Same with 戦いで怪我をした. I can't see the usage in any dictionaries unless 場所 is being used in some abstract sense to just refer to the setting in which the action takes place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty much as you described it. In this case, で is more of an "in", but not for a time or place, rather a setting. The same usage is seen in English, too, like

> - "I injured myself in battle"
> - "I hurt myself in [a game of] soccer".

It's pretty intuitive, and the same happens in many languages, with the reasoning being that you're treating "battle" as "the time when I was in battle" (although obviously not in so many words).